# Node import and performance question

Tags: drupal, import, drupal-7

For one of my clients I have to import a CSV of Medicare plans provided by the government (part one provided [here](http://www.medicare.gov/download/DownloaddbInterim.asp)) into Drupal 7. There are about 500,000 rows of data in that CSV, most of which differ only by the FIPS County code field - basically, every county that a plan is available in counts as one row.

Should I import all 500k rows into Drupal 7 as individual nodes, or create a single node for every plan and put the numerous FIPS codes associated with that plan in a multi-value text field? I opted for the latter route to begin with, however when I looked in the plan database it looks like some plans are available in more than 10,000 counties. I'd like to find the most efficient, Drupal-esque solution to storing all these plans and where they are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a row per plan - as it turned out, there were subtle differences between them that I missed. Thanks to all who answered!

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is very useful to avoid storing any duplicate data, so you are right, create 500k rows as individual nodes is a bad idea. I would rather create two content types (using [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/CCK)):

1. Medicare Plan
2. FIPS County code (or maybe just County)

And then create a [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between them (using CCK Node Reference, maybe [Corresponding node references](http://drupal.org/project/cnr) for mutual relationships if needed).

You can then create a view that will list all FIPS County codes attached to a particular Medicare Plan.